# Building a list of shortest path and relationship from a CSV file in python

Tags: python, list, csv, shortest-path

I need your help on an incomplete code which I wrote to handle the issue I have.

So I have this input file :-

```
-----INPUT : test2.csv-----
child, parent, relation
M3,Q,P
M54,M7,P
M54,M27,E
Q,M7,P
M7,Q,E
M7,M3,P
M27,Q,E

======OUTPUT REQUIRED====
M3->Q,P
M54->M7->Q,P
M7->Q,E
M27->Q,E
```

==================PROBLEM EXPLANATION===================

Q is the ultimate parent. I want to trace all childs back to Q (the shortest path to parent 'Q').
For example for the first row, the output should be =

```
M3->Q, P
```

But second row, M54 is child of M7 with a relation tag of 'P' (M54->M7, P), but we need to traverse M7 to the ultimate parent who is 'Q'. As we search through along the csv file for M7's parent, we see that from row 5 & 6, M7 can have either 'M3' as his parent or 'Q' as his parent. So we have two paths tracing to the ultimate parent Q :-

```
M54->M7->Q,PE & M54->M7->M3->Q,PPP
```

But we would like to have the shortest path only , i.e.

```
M54->M7->Q,PE
```

Another issue is that we also have cyclic paths, eg consider row 4 & 5 :-

```
Q,M7,P
M7,Q,E
```

So in such a case we would like the output as M7->Q,E (rather than Q->M7->Q as one would expect).

This is the code Ive come up with so far :-

```
# Read the csv file
import csv
z=[]
with open('test2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        z.append(row)        

# Now generate list-of-list to store relations. Eg [['M7', 'Q', ['P']],.....
for i in range(len(z)):
    t=z[i].pop()
    z[i].append([t])

# Now lets populate the list   
t=[]    
out=[]
for i in range(len(z)):
    child = z[i][0]
    if z[i][1]=='Q': #whos the parent ?
            out.append(z[i])
            continue
    t.append(z[i])
    index=t.index(z[i])
    print (index)
    parent=t[index][1]
    print (parent)
    length=len(t[index])
    for j in range(len(z)):
        if z[j][0] == child:
            if z[j][1]=='Q':
                t[index].insert(length,'Q')

#print (parent)
print ("temp=",t)
print ("out=",out)
```

Comment: With what exactly you are having a problem?

Comment: Hi Ramchandra ji, Ive edited my post and included the output required. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution heavily based on [this essay on Python.org](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html):

```
from pprint import pformat
import csv


def graph_from_csv(filename):
    """Turn a CSV of child, parent, relation entries into a graph represented
    by a dictionary, for example:

    {'A': [('B', 'ab'), ('C', 'ac')],
     'B': [('C','bc'), ('D','bd')],
     'C': [('D','cd')],
     'D': [('C','dc')]}
"""
    rows = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        # Skip header row
        next(reader, None)

        for row in reader:
            rows.append(row)


    graph = dict()
    for row in rows:
        child, parent, relation = row
        if not parent in graph:
            graph[parent] = []
        graph[parent].append((child, relation))

    return graph


def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end, path=[], relations=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path, relations
    if not start in graph:
        return (None, None)
    shortest = None
    shortest_rels = None
    for node, relation in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath, newrelations = find_shortest_path(graph, node, end, path,
                                                       relations + [relation])
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                    shortest_rels = newrelations
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest, shortest_rels


def format_output(path, relations):
    p = '->'.join(path)
    r = ''.join(relations)
    return "%s,%s" % (p, r)


def main():
    graph = graph_from_csv('test2.csv')
    print("Graph:")
    print(pformat(graph))
    print()

    start, end = 'Q', 'M54'
    path, relations = find_shortest_path(graph, start, end)
    print("Shortest path from '%s' to '%s'" % (start, end))
    print(format_output(path, relations))
    print()

    start, end = 'Q', 'M7'
    path, relations = find_shortest_path(graph, start, end)
    print("Shortest path from '%s' to '%s'" % (start, end))
    print(format_output(path, relations))
    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Graph:
{'M27': [('M54', 'E')],
 'M3': [('M7', 'P')],
 'M7': [('M54', 'P'), ('Q', 'P')],
 'Q': [('M3', 'P'), ('M7', 'E'), ('M27', 'E')]}

Shortest path from 'Q' to 'M54'
Q->M7->M54,EP

Shortest path from 'Q' to 'M7'
Q->M7,E
```

You will notice that the direction for the path query and the resulting path is inverted compared to your example (from ancestor to child) - this is just how the original `find_shortest_path` function from the essay implemented the parent -> child relationship in a directed graph - and I stuck with it, because I feel that's the most natural way to represent it.

If you do want to invert it though, simply using [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) on the respective lists (`path` and `relations`) and switching `start` and `end` will do the trick.

---

**(1)** This line warrants some explanation I think:

```
path = path + [start]
```

Why not just append to `path`? This is being done because `path=[]` is a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument), and if you would append to `path`, you would end up changing that default argument for all further calls to that function.

Comment: Thanks a lot Graf. But I get this error while running it : -  python3 ~/ml/matrix/csv_graph.py /tmp/test2.csv 
  File "/home/vanilla/ml/matrix/csv_graph.py", line 62
    print "Graph:"
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ah, I used Python 2.7, and you're using Python3, where `print` is a function, not a statement. Hang on, I'll update my code.

Comment: Sir Im trying it on various input files that I have. So that I could get back to yo in case of any issues. Thanks a lot for the code and the python essay link,that was really informative. Im trying to understand the essay too.

Comment: Please help. The program fails on this input file  http://www.filedropper.com/sampleinput

Comment: @Sunita The solution I provided works for the example input in your question. So if it works for that, please accept the answer, and if it doesn't work for other input, make that a new question. In that question, include the input *inline*, not as a link, and details on how it "doesn't work" (error message, stack trace, ...).

Comment: Dear Lukas, I found the issue with my error. Actually I gave 1 100 line input file, but as your code prints hardcoded shortest paths for only two of them ('Q' to 'M54', & 'Q' to 'M7') therefore it was failing. So could you please tell me how to modify your code (in the main() call ) so that it automatically prints the shortest path for all the children (tracing them to their parent Q) . Because if I have hundred of children , them I cant call the all one by one so as to print the shortest for each. Thus it would be helpful if you could modify it to work like this.

Comment: Lukas Ive posted it as  a different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546291/shortest-path-and-relationship-from-a-csv-file-in-python